# Partial interface implementation when you cannot extend a abstract class in java

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, partial

Suppose I have an interface which has 3 methods. This interface is to be implemented by many classes but the implementation of say method1 will be same in all classes.

I can make an abstract class and give a concrete implementation for method1 and let my classes extend this class.

My question is when I am already extending a class, how do I also extend this abstract class. Java doesn't support it. How should I design in such a scenario?

```
interface Inf{
 void method1();
 void method2();
 void method3();
}

public abstract class Abs implements Inf{
 void method1(){
  //concrete implementation
 }
}

class Test extends SomeClass implements Inf{
   //here I need method1 implementation and other methods Ill implement
}

class SomeClass{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With java 8, you can define default implementation of a method inside the interface.

```
public interface A {
    default void method1() { System.out.println("Default method1 implementation"); }
    void method2();
    void method3();
}
```

Comment: This definitely is a solution, but what on older versions of java? How to handle then, I am thinking more from a design perspective.

Comment: In that case you will have an abstract class which implements the default method and in your API design, you require subclasses of this abstract class instead of the interface.

Comment: That returns to my first question, say my class is already extending a class and I cannot edit this super class to extend my abstract class. How do I handle in such scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support `Multiple Inheritance`. i.e A Class cannot have more than one Base class. What you can do is make the `SomeClass` to extend `Abs` class

```
class SomeClass extends Abs{

}

class Test extends SomeClass implements Inf{
   //here you can get method1 implementation since Someclass extends Abs
}
```

Note : As said by @anonymous , you can make use of `default methods` of `interface` if you work in Java 8

Comment: Here the problem is SomeClass now has to  implement all methods of the interface. The other solution being Abs does not implement the interface, just gives the concrete implementation of the method1(). But I don't think that is a proper implementation. Maybe some change in design?

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support multiple inheritance.
You can make your Abs class to extend SomeClass

```
class Abs extends SomeClass {

}

class Test extends Abs implements Inf {
}
```